# Combining samples quickly in tone.js (or another framework)

Tags: tone.js

I need to programatically combine a bunch of music tracks in a sequence, one after the other, with some overlap between them, based on some rules.

I was looking at tone.js today which is great, and I've just about managed to make work (with players feeding into a recorder), but I realised right at the end that you have to wait for the whole sequence to play out in real time before it can be saved.

I don't want to have to wait an hour to get the file, I need it within a minute maximum. Is this possible with tone.js and if not is there any other programmatic way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use OfflineContext rendering for this. Basically what you have to do is calling `Tone.Offline` and then get the audioBuffer of the result and save it to a file. You don't need a Recorder node. So something like this:

```js
const audioBufferNode = await Tone.Offline(({ transport }) => {
  // Do all your player scheduling along the transport here.

  transport.start(0.5); // Start the transport to trigger all scheduled players
}, 4 /* The length of the resulting file */);
```

To download the audio buffer as a file requires you to read the raw data and write it into a format you wish to download.

A audio buffer to wave writer can be found here:
https://www.russellgood.com/how-to-convert-audiobuffer-to-audio-file